# Install openexr in python doesn't work

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-import, apt-get, openexr

I have successfully installed *openexr* using `pip install openexr` on my mac, but the same command fails on Ubuntu:

```
OpenEXR.cpp:9:22: fatal error: ImathBox.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for openex
```

I tried using `apt-get install openexr` which seems like to install without an error but then when I try to `import OpenEXR` in python, it doesn't work.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 15):

You need to install the apt package "libopenexr-dev" this will resolve the pip issue.

I didn't have this issue on the mac, a "brew install openexr" must've installed the headers also.

Answer (score 12):

Works as recently as Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenexr-dev
sudo apt-get install openexr
```

`pip install OpenEXR --user`

Answer (score 4):

You first need to install **zlib** by:

```
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: It works for solving the error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz`.

Answer (score 1):

openexr is only the c++ implementation. You need the py-openexr to be able to use in python. You can find how to install on this link

http://excamera.com/sphinx/articles-openexr.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this:

```
sudo apt-get install openexr,
sudo apt-get install libopenexr-dev,
pip install openexr
```